# Multi dimensional Arrays

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multi[2][3] = {{17, 23, 19}, {72, 34, 44}};

int main()
{
    printf("%p\n", multi);    //line 1
    printf("%p\n", *multi);   //line 2

    if(*multi == multi)
        puts("They are equal!");

    return 0;
}
```

How line 1 and 2 is different?

I'm getting output :

```
They are equal
```

Also can somebody refer a good tutorial on pointers and its use with multidimensional arrays .. .

Answer (score 2):

The value is the same but the type is different.

`multi` is of type `int [2][3]` and when evaluated it is converted to the type `int (*)[3]`

`*multi` is of type `int [3]` and when evaluated it is of type `int *`.

Actually:

```
*multi == multi
```

is accepted by your compiler but the expression is not valid in C because the two operands of the `==` operators are of different types. To perform the comparison you would need to cast one of the two operands.

Comment: You can compare two pointers of different types in C, actually.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII the constraint of the `==` operators for pointers operands require `both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types` (C99, 6.5.9p2)

Comment: and of course `int *` and `int (*)[3]` are not compatible types.

Comment: @ouah yes you can compare them due to the very reason both are pointer , eliminating the fact to what they point to

Comment: @Mr.Anubis please read my previous comments, short: you cannot.

Comment: Just for completeness, comparing pointers of different types is okay if one is a pointer to an object type and the other a (possibly qualified) `void*`. (And every pointer may be compared to a null pointer constant.) Of course the clause relevant here is the one quoted above.

Answer (score 2):

The question to you your answer is given by gcc when you compile your code:

```
ml.c:10: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
```

`multi` is a type of 2 dimensional `int` array. that is `int[][]`

Where `*multi` is a type of 1 dimensional `int` array. That is `int[]`

That's why they are not the same object. One has to be cast to be eligible for comparison. Lets see how this **wrong** code works under the hood.

Surprisingly there's no `cmp` instruction at all!(compiled with `-g -O0`). Actually you don't need a `cmp` here. Because `multi` will be decayed to a pointer to `&multi[0][0]`. and `*multi` will be decayed to `&multi[0]`. So from the memory's point of view, they are the same, and c compiler happily optimizes them (even with `-O0` :)).

```
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400504 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000000000400505 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
=> 0x0000000000400508 <+4>: mov    eax,0x400648
   0x000000000040050d <+9>: mov    esi,0x600900
   0x0000000000400512 <+14>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000000000400515 <+17>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000000000040051a <+22>:    call   0x4003f0 <printf@plt>
   0x000000000040051f <+27>:    mov    edx,0x600900
   0x0000000000400524 <+32>:    mov    eax,0x400648
   0x0000000000400529 <+37>:    mov    rsi,rdx
   0x000000000040052c <+40>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x000000000040052f <+43>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000400534 <+48>:    call   0x4003f0 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000400539 <+53>:    mov    edi,0x40064c
   0x000000000040053e <+58>:    call   0x400400 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400543 <+63>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000400548 <+68>:    leave  
   0x0000000000400549 <+69>:    ret
```

only thing its doing before calling `puts()` is moving the address of the string which it should print into argument register.

```
gdb) x/10cb 0x40064c
0x40064c <__dso_handle+12>: 84 'T'  104 'h' 101 'e' 121 'y' 32 ' '  97 'a'  114 'r' 101 'e'
0x400654 <__dso_handle+20>: 32 ' '  101 'e'
```

There you go, you are confusing the compiler enough :) that it stripped away the `cmp` may with a `always true` optimization. :)

Expert C programming has a chapter named (surprise! surprise!)

> Chapter 4. The Shocking Truth: C Arrays and Pointers Are NOT the Same!

Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile with -Wall, the compiler will warn you about the line (cause: `comparison of distinct pointer types`):

if(*multi == multi)

`multi` is array and in C his address is the address of his first element aka `multi[0]`.
`*multi` is pointer to the first element of the array aka multi[0].

You are comparing two addresses that contain the same data: (`{17, 23, 19}`), which explain why you get this output.

Hope this help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In brief in C a matrix is stored as a series of consecutive arrays wich are the rows of the matrix :

m has type pointer to array of 3 ints
  and is the address of the first array / row of the matrix

m* has type pointer to int
   and is the address of the first
   element of the first row

the same apply to m+1 wich is the address of the second array
and for *( m + 1 ) wich is the address of the first element of the second array/row.

hope this helps.